# Error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/main.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am unable to understand the error. It says

```
*Error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http:// localhost:3000/app/main.ts
at o (system.src.js:4597)
at XMLHttpRequest.I.s.onreadystatechange (system.src.js:4597)*
```

This is my **app.component.cs**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";<br/>
import {ListComponent} from "./List/list.component";<br/>
import {ContactComponent} from "./Contact/contact-form.component";

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
{{title}} 
<a routerLink="/myList"></a><router-outlet></router-outlet>
`    
})

export class AppComponent {
title: 'My Angular App';
}
```

This is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from './List/list.component'

@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'myList',
            component: ListComponent
        }
    ])],

declarations: [AppComponent,ListComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],


})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my **main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular App</title>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-        shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/syst
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script> 
<base href="/">
<script>
        System.config ({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './app' }
        });
            System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

This is my **systemjs.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
 System.config({
    paths: {

      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },

    map: {

      app: 'app',


'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
'@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
'@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
 '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
'@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
'@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
'@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',


'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },

        packages: {
          app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

last but not the least, this is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
  ,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I got many solutions but none of them worked for me. I don't know what's wrong, and I am new to Angular 2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The System.config you have in your index.html is for transpiling in the browser.  The only time you'd want to do that is if you're creating a plunker example.  For development, you'd use something like this in index.html

```
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

For production, you'd do Ahead of Time transpiling.

I suggest you start over with the Quickstart example at https://angular.io/guide/quickstart